How to add a default static rout to a VyOS router
I'm new to VyOS. For testing purposes I have it installed on hyper-V. The VyOS has 3 active interfaces, eth0 and eth1 are for the servers and clients. I want eth2 to connect to the default switch in hyper-V.
show ip route
C* 192.168.11.0/24 directly connected, eth0, 01:13:15
C* 192.168.12.0/24 directly connected, eth1, 01:13:15

I have tried different ways of configuring this, but nothing seems to work. For example:
set protocols static interface-route 0.0.0.0/0 next-hop-interface eth2

Configuration path: Protocols static [interface-route] is not valid
Set failed


the command is:
set interfaces ethernet eth2 <CIDR address default gateway hyper-v guest>

